# Simplify $\log(\sinh z)$ when $|z|$ tends to $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I was given $\log(\sinh z)$ and I need to show it tends to $\log z$ when $|z|$ tends to $0$.

I have tried converting $z$ to $x+iy$ then split $\sinh z$ but that doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

I know $\log z=\log|z|+i{\rm Arg}(z)$ but I have no idea how to use this.

Any hint would be helpful thanks!

Comment: It's true that $z=x+iy$ but it is also true that $z=re^{i\theta}$ and since the hyperbolic function consist of e-powers...

Comment: @imranfat Would you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: I concurr with Marty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
\sinh(z)
&=\dfrac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2}\\
&\approx \dfrac{(1+z+z^2/2)-(1-z+z^2/2)}{2}
\quad\text{(for small z)}\\
&=z
\end{array}
$

Now take $\ln$.

Comment: Indeed, Taylor expansions are so often the answer.

Comment: I put a missing bracket behind the second 2 in that denom. But indeed, this was what I was thinking in my comment! +1